# Jackson custom annotation for custom NULL value serialization

Tags: java, jackson

According to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342675/5810648

I wrote such serializer:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Double> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private final NAifNull annotation;

    public CustomSerializer() {
        super(Double.class);
        this.annotation = null;
    }

    public CustomSerializer(NAifNull annotation) {
        super(Double.class);
        this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (annotation != null && value == null) {
            gen.writeString("N/A");
        } else {
            gen.writeNumber(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {
        NAifNull annotation = property.getAnnotation(NAifNull.class);
        return new CustomSerializer(annotation);
    }
}
```

Witch supposed to write string "N/A" if the annotation is present and field is `null`. But method `serialize` is called only for not null fields.

Also, I have tried to call `setNullValueSerializer`:

```
@Override
public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {
    NAifNull annotation = property.getAnnotation(NAifNull.class);
    prov.setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer(annotation));
    return new CustomSerializer(annotation);
}
```

With such implementation:

```
private static class CustomNullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    private final NAifNull annotation;

    public CustomNullSerializer(NAifNull annotation) {
        this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (annotation != null) {
            gen.writeString("N/A");
        } else {
            gen.writeNull();
        }
    }
}
```

But no result.

How to handle null fields in such way?

**Update**

According to discussion:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2057

```
prov.setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer(annotation));
```

Is not supposed to be called from `CreateContextual` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [`BeanSerializerModifier`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) to customize the null serializer for a *particular property*:

```java
public class CustomBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, 
           BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {

        for (BeanPropertyWriter beanProperty : beanProperties) {
            if (beanProperty.getAnnotation(NAifNull.class) != null) {
                beanProperty.assignNullSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer());
            }
        }

        return beanProperties;
    }
}
```

Where `@NAifNull` and `CustomNullSerializer` are define as follows:

```java
public class CustomNullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, 
           SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString("N/A");
    }
}
```

```java
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NAifNull {

}
```

Then use it as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule() {

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new CustomBeanSerializerModifier());
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to use this solution to serialize null values to a default value **depending on the actual type** of the null value, e.g. null String => `""`, null Number => `"0"`, as standard serializer `serialize()` callback is never called by null values. I just did: `new SimpleModule().setSerializerModifier(...)` for the setup. Thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to write "N/A" to generated JSON, if the value is null.

[Jackson docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html#serialize) states that value cannot be null. This is because the type parameter is Class object, which is [constructed automatically by JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html?is-external=true).

As per this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map-null-values-or-null-key), I think you could handle null fields with something like

```
public class CustomNullSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

   public CustomNullSerializer() {
        this(null);
   }

   public CustomNullSerializer(Class<Object> t) {
        super(t);
   }

   @Override
   public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString("N/A");
   }
}
```

And then use it with

```
prov.setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer());
```

Thought I didn't try this myself, but I hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Okey, now I had time to try this myself. I got it working with

```
ObjectMapper mapper...
mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work and also see question updates.