# Disable field serialization per ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, mixins

I'm developing a REST application using `application/json` Content-Type (server). I'm developing the REST client library for it as well (client). Both server and client use the same Jackson annotated classes/resources.

One of my server use cases includes adding a field which should be write-only (enable only deserialization). I do it like this:

```java
public class MyClass {

  @JsonProperty(access = WRITE_ONLY)
  private String field;

  ...

}
```

However, since this class is used on the client side too, I am unable to send value to this field because the serialization processing skips it. I want the client to be able serialize this field. The server and client use separate object mappers.

I can use separate implementations of `JsonSerializer<MyClass>` and set it to the object mapper but this mean that I have to serialize all other fields manually. I don't want this.

I am wondering, if there is some way to instruct object mapper (or inject something into it) to handle such field differently?

Comment: You could try using a custom annotation like `@Server` and implement this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342097/jackson-custom-annotation-for-custom-value-serialization
Shared module between server and client could have methods like `getServerObjectMapper()` and `getClientObjectMapper()`, which would have this serializer added or not accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know how this fit into my case. In the example `@JsonSerialize(using = UnitSerializer.class)` is used onto the field . So it is automatically resolved in runtime. Programmatically, I only can add serializer per certain type. Also, I don't want to introduce shared module by now if it is possible

Comment: using @JsonIgnore on getter method Only, answer in the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505141/only-using-jsonignore-during-serialization-but-not-deserialization)

Comment: @NasirHussain, it works on the server side when. However, on the client side when I send this field, jackson ignores it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use common model classes on two sides: client and server you can register all differences using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` class and its implementations. In case, some `Jackson` configuration should be available only on one side you can move it to [MixIn](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) classes/interfaces and register only on given side.

Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ClientServerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Client side
        ObjectMapper clientMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

        // create payload on client side
        MyClass instance = new MyClass(1, "fieldValue");
        String payload = clientMapper.writeValueAsString(instance);

        // send to server
        System.out.println("Send: " + payload);
        // ..

        // Server side
        ObjectMapper serverMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new ServerModule())
                .build();
        MyClass deserialized = serverMapper.readValue(payload, MyClass.class);
        System.out.println("Deserialized: " + deserialized);

        System.out.println("Payload on server side: " + serverMapper.writeValueAsString(deserialized));
    }
}

class ServerModule extends SimpleModule {
    public ServerModule() {
        setMixInAnnotation(MyClass.class, MyClassServerMixIn.class);
        // add other configuration
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class MyClass {

    private int id;
    private String field;
}

interface MyClassServerMixIn {

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    String getField();
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Send: {"id":1,"field":"fieldValue"}
Deserialized: MyClass(id=1, field=fieldValue)
Payload on server side: {"id":1}
```

As you can notice, only `ObjectMapper` on client side can serialise `field` property.

Comment: I figured it out  yesterday and now I see your answer. It is exact the same think that I found. Anyway, I left it to collect more suggestions. This one handle this case nicely, so I mark it as resolved :).